# How to print different number of columns in 3-row table using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I was research about this, but didn't find proper solution. So, I would like to create table using FPDF that have 3 rows and different number of columns in every row.

```
function MyTable($header, $data){


$w = array(63, 63, 63);

for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
    $this->Cell($w[$i],4,$header[$i],1,0,'L');
$this->Ln();


foreach($data as $row)
{
    $x=$this->GetX();
    $y=$this->GetY();
    $push_right = 0;

    foreach($row as $col){
    $this->Cell($push_right,4,$col,'LR');
    $this->Ln();
    }
    $push_right = $x + 63;
    $this->SetXY($push_right,97);
}
$this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');}
```

And call :

```
$pdf = new PDF();
 $pdf->AliasNbPages();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont('Times','',16);
 $header = array('Alergije','Hronicne bolesti','Rizici');
 $data = array(array('Penicilin','Latex'),array('Hipertenzija','Dijabetes','Secer'),array('Rizik 1','Rizik 2','Rizik 3','Rizik 4'));
 $pdf->MyTable($header,$data);
  $pdf->Output();
```

Output is this :

[image]

And my goal is to get this : 
[image]

As You can see, first value in every column is properly positioned , but I can not find where is the error for the rest values.

I will really appreciate some advise.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with FPDF functions, positioning setXY(), than drawing rectangle with Rect(), and finally write data into MultiCell().